# How to add color picker in mfc?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want be able to select any color I want, just like the attached pic.

[image: COLOR PICKER]

Yes I want to learn this C++ or MFC. I find it more powerful. Could you explain to me exactly how to add it to my project? I also want the color itself and it code appears in picture box and textbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CColorDialog` class in mfc is used to pick the color from MFC

```
 // Get the selected color from the CColorDialog. 
 CColorDialog dlg; 
 if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) 
 { 
      COLORREF color = dlg.GetColor(); 

 }
```

This sample will popup dialog to select the color and after selecting the color and click ok button then color variable will contain the selected color.

Use this color in your application.

**EDIT**

You can customize your combo box or list box to add the color pick tool.

Refer this link : [CodeProjectSample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/colourpickercb.aspx)

Comment: @user : This will popup the dialog but i want like the above attachment.

Comment: @karthik: For that you have to customize the combobox and write in the way you like.

Answer (score 4):

[`CMFCColorDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982523.aspx) or [`CColorDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccolordialog-class?view=msvc-170) is what you seem to be looking for. To make it act like a drop-down, you'll need to position it below the down-arrow button (e.g., using `MoveWindow`).

`CColorDialog` creates the "old standard" color picker dialog, like this:

[image]

`CMFCColorDialog` creates the somewhat newer color picker, like this one:

[image]

Comment: how to include CMFCColorDialog in to my application.when i use this , it will show the error as CMFCColorDialog undeclared identifier.

Comment: You need either VS 2008 with the Feature Pack or SP1, or else VS 2010 to use it. Assuming you have that, `#include <afxcolordialog.h>`.

Comment: I am not having that version.Is any other possible way to achieve this?

Comment: With older versions/compilers, it's easiest to use a CColorDialog instead (or you can call ChooseColor directly). At least in theory, you should be able to create the drop-down color picker directly via its COM interface, but I've never tried it, so I can't really say much about how to do it.

Comment: What is the difference between `CColorDialog` and `CMFCColorDialog`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I've edited to show an example of each.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't seem to have the MFC Feature Pack, check the Ultimate Toolbox at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox.aspx. Its Graphical User Interface classes have a [Color Picker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox_GUI.aspx#Color_Picker).

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio versions prior 2008, you can use BCGSoft's color pikcer (http://www.bcgsoft.com). MFC color dialog is based on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `CMFCColorButton`. I added the graphic resource with the ToolBox on my dialog design, but I could't assign a control variable because it did not recognize `CMFCColorButton`.

The answer was to include `afxcolorbutton.h` in the header of `stdafx.h`. Maybe you can fix it in the same way.

I hope this helps